# Performing data functions in Hive where the date format contains characters that need escaping

Tags: date, hadoop, hive, format

I'm receiving dates in the format:

yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mms.SSSZ

so when I try to perform date functions the single quote is causing problems.

I've tried escaping the single quotes with a slash () but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you please give a data sample so I can be sure of the format?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like below for getting date out of it.:-

```
select to_date(translate("2016-12-12'T'12:12.342", "'|T"," ")) from dummy limit 1;
```

for getting whole timestamp you can use regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2017-02-17T14:27:58.000Z', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"));
OK
2017-02-17 14:27:58
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation along with your code.